# Consuming JSON WCF on Silverlight

Tags: json, wcf, silverlight

I'm want to try changing a SOAP WCF to accept requests and return results in JSON format to make the data traffic less bulky.

I see that JSON requests functions looks like this:

> wcfClient.OpenReadAsync(http://yourUrl.com/wcf/service1.svc/GetEmployees)

and do the regular SOAP requests functions instead that looks like :

> wcfClient.GetEmployeesAsync();

1) For JSON results, do you need to parse them into an object or is it automatically parsed like SOAP?

2) Is there a way to do this without doing too much work like changing every single WCF calls in the project to looks "JSON-ish"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the idea "make the data traffic less bulky." is good.

Especially for Mobile devices. Beside this don't think that WCF xml causes network issues for PC. XM is the one of most compressible format. By WCF binary it goes as compressed.

**For "Is there a way to do this without doing too much work?"**

Yes there is a way name on it RESTFul Services(Restless Services). Now Microsoft directly support it by WEBApi.

Also you may use ODATA for filtering,ordering operations

Here are some links,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/06/14/how-to-do-api-key-verification-for-rest-services-in-net-4.aspx

ODATA
http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions#FilterSystemQueryOption

A few practice notes,Some restrictions:

EntityFrameWork entities derived from EntityObject which has IsReferenceType attribute doesn't allow you to JSON serialize. ( I produced POCO objects using an automapper mapped them and serialized json)

WEBAPI support you much think such as WebGet,WebInvoke GetXML Give JSON ,ODATA features(just select and format not allowed.)

Note:In your web request's header you should accept text/json to get really json.

**"For JSON results, do you need to parse them into an object or..."**

I can say you should try [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) it's portable library works everywhere. When you deserialize with a generic function it returns you the collection you expect.

Hope it helps someone. While discovering these stackoverflow helped me like an assistant.

Answer (score 2):

To complement Davut's answer - WCF does support building RESTful services, although I agree that the [ASP.NET Web API](http://asp.net/webapi) framework in general easier to use than WCF. JSON.NET is a great library, and it has nice deserialization capabilities (e.g., it can easily take the JSON which represent the list of `Employee` objects and convert them into the actual `List<Employee>` instance)

But for completeness sake, if you want to use a "normal" WCF client to access WCF-based services which return JSON, you can do it. It's not too straightforward, but you can do that by using a new encoder and behavior which does the conversion. The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/04/29/consuming-rest-json-services-in-silverlight-4.aspx talks more about it, and has a pointer to a code sample.

In short, it's possible to consume JSON using a WCF client in Silverlight, but due to its complexity it's usually not done, and Davut's option (use a HTTP client such as WebClient to download JSON, then a library such as JSON.NET to parse it into objects) is preferred.